# Texts in rect d3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to put two different texts in one rect in d3. 
My first text is a command (ex : save) and the seconde one is its shortcut (ctrl-s). 
I would like to have the command in the left and the shortcut in the right, like a normal menu.
I would also like to make the size of the rectangle to adapt the max size of the two texts so it can be beautiful.

I tried this

```
nodeEnter.selectAll("text.labels")
            .data(labels)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".45em")
            .attr("y", barHeight/2)
            .attr("dx" , whereFun)
            .style("visibility", visible)
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

nodeEnter.selectAll("text.values")
            .append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".45em")
            .attr("y", barHeight/2)
            .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.width + 10; })
            .text(function(d) {if (d.hotkeyChar) { return racc[d.modifiers] + "+" + d.hotkeyChar;}});



var maxTextWidth = d3.max(texts, function() {
            return d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width;
});

    nodeEnter.append("rect")
          .attr("height", barHeight)
          .attr("width", maxTextWidth)
          .style("fill", color)
          .on("click", click)
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
              .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

but its not working... the two texts block everything and it doesnt show anything. (not errors in console).
Hope you understand what i need and thank you.

Comment: It sounds like SVG isn't the right choice here. I would go with a HTML `div` and the appropriate CSS.

Comment: i doesnt change anything in my problem

Comment: @Pet, it would change your problem, because then you'd be able to `display:inline-block` the two texts (which would become divs or spans) and the parent container would automatically grow to fit both, and you won't need to measure the texts or adjust `dy` or `y` etc. At any rate, it looks like there might be issues with the d3 code you're using to create the elements. When you inspect it in dev tools, do you see the DOM hierarchy you expect? If nothing else, it's important to remember that when you `selectAll` using a class (e.g. `.labels`) you also need to add the class after you `append`.

Comment: oh ok! Yes my d3 code for reading is correct! i see the correct DOM hierarchy. i didnt think about the `display` for the  div. thank you very much meetamit.